# Method paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.1

When I do:

```
    $tournaments =  Tournament::paginate(Config::get('constants.PAGINATION'));
```

it works, but I just need tournaments that owns the user.

So I do:

```
    $tournaments = Auth::user()->tournaments;
    $tournaments->paginate(Config::get('constants.PAGINATION'));
```

I have a hasMany Relationship in user model

And I get this message

```
Method paginate does not exist.
```

How can I solve it? It doesn't seem complicated, but I can't do it!

EDIT:
@smartrahat

Result of the second query: Auth::user()->tournaments

```
Collection {#385 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
0 => Tournament {#386 ▼
  #table: "tournament"
  +timestamps: true
  #fillable: array:17 [▶]
  #dates: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:16 [▶]
  #original: array:16 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
]  
}
```

Result of the first query:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#428 ▼
#total: 2
#lastPage: 1
#items: Collection {#430 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
  0 => Tournament {#431 ▼
    #table: "tournament"
    +timestamps: true
    #fillable: array:17 [▶]
    #dates: array:2 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    #attributes: array:16 [▶]
    #original: array:16 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  1 => Tournament {#432 ▶}
]
}
#perPage: "20"
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://laravel.dev:8000/tournaments"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
```

Comment: I resolved it using: $tournaments = Tournament::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->paginate(Config::get('constants.PAGINATION'));; but I still doesn't understand why is it behaving like that

Comment: In your first query `$tournaments` returning a collection but in second query `$tournaments` returning only a column value. Try `dd($tournaments)` in your second query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your question you are calling `paginate()` on a Collection more than likely.

In the answer that works you are calling `paginate()` on an eloquent builder.

```
Auth::user()->tournaments; // dynamic property for relationship, probably a collection

Auth::user()->tournaments(); // relation type object (eloquent builder)
```

Your answer:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->paginate(Config::get('constants.PAGINATION'));
```

`where` is returning the eloquent builder that you are calling `paginate` on.

This should give you the same result:

```
$tournaments = Auth::user()->tournaments()->paginate(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->paginate(Config::get('constants.PAGINATION'));;
```

but I still doesn't understand why is it behaving like that

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: In second query, is it return data of all users or only current user?

Comment: in the second one, it doesn't work : Method paginate does not exist

Comment: After `dd($tournaments)` expand the `#original` and see which users data are returning.